# Mysql search query LIKE without hyphen can't find record with hyphen in record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I'm using codeigniter to search in table 'videos' for videos that have boolean show_search set to '1' and naslov or opis should be LIKE php string $query.
$query is what users pass in input form.

```
if($query) $this->db->where("show_search AND (naslov LIKE '%$query%' OR opis LIKE '%$query%')");
```

The above is working fine for most queries made.

The problem is when I have a record with hyphen in the middle of string: opis ="DORS/CLUC 2016 - LibreOffice moves online".

Example query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE show_search AND (naslov LIKE '%DORS/CLUC 2016 - LibreOffice moves online%' OR opis LIKE '%DORS/CLUC 2016 - LibreOffice moves online%')
```

this return's a correct query.

Example query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE show_search AND (naslov LIKE '%DORS/CLUC 2016 LibreOffice moves online%' OR opis LIKE '%DORS/CLUC 2016 LibreOffice moves online%')
```

Doesn't return any query.

SO my question is if users enter "DORS/CLUC 2016 LibreOffice moves online" how can i match the record with hyphen (DORS/CLUC 2016 - LibreOffice moves online)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they are actually different characters that just look similar.

For example, the query might contain a [Hyphen-Minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) while the data might contain a Minus Sign.

These Unicode code points have very similar appearances:

- U+002D - HYPHEN-MINUS
- U+2010 ‐ HYPHEN
- U+2011 ‑ NON-BREAKING HYPHEN
- U+2212 − MINUS SIGN
- U+2013 – EN DASH
- U+2014 — EM DASH

To check what characters you have in your database and your query, copy and paste them into a lookup tool such as [Wolfram/Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%E2%88%92).

Answer (score 0):

You could replace non-word characters with a wildcard.

```php
$query = "DORS/CLUC   2016 - LibreOffice moves online";

$query = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '%', $query);

var_export($query); //-> 'DORS%CLUC%2016%LibreOffice%moves%online'
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/99adb7a3-4757-449f-b092-915ea6c5efdc